# Fractional day difference in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 2 columns, `EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP`, `EFFECTIVE_DATE` as dates.

I want the difference between the two columns expressed as a fractional day. e.g. 1.5 days.

Is the following the only way to do it? Surely there must be a better way?

```
select EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP - EFFECTIVE_DATE,
       extract(day from (EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP - EFFECTIVE_DATE))
        +(extract(hour from (EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP - EFFECTIVE_DATE)))/24
        +extract(minute from (EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP - EFFECTIVE_DATE))/1400
        +extract(second from (EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP - EFFECTIVE_DATE))/86400
 from a_table
```

Comment: What's wrong with `select EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP - EFFECTIVE_DATE from a_table;` ?

Comment: Simple `EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP - EFFECTIVE_DATE` is enough. It gives you difference in days between two dates. Moreover, your usage of `extract()` function is semantically incorrect. `extract()` function expects to see datetime or interval as a value you are extracting from, not a numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just to subtract the two values like

```
SELECT sysdate - (sysdate -dbms_random.value(1,10)) FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this example:

```
SELECT ROUND(to_date('02/26/2014 05:00:15 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') - 
             to_date('02/25/2014 06:00:15 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),1) Days
FROM DUAL;
```

It will Give output `1.5`.

Answer (score 0):

And if you use timestamps, you need to cast them to dates, e.g. `ROUND(CAST(timestamp1 as DATE) - CAST(timestamp2 as DATE), 1)`